# Atualizar estado do carrinho sem sair da página | Woocommerce 3.4+

Tags: php, wordpress, funções, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

```
<?php global $woocommerce; 
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) < 1 ) { ?>
    <div style="width: 25%;" class="footer-section <?php echo esc_html($woo);?>">
        <a href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>" title="Main"><i class="fa  fa-home"></i></a>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div style="width: 20%;" class="footer-section <?php echo esc_html($woo);?>">
        <a href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>" title="Main"><i class="fa  fa-home"></i></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

O estado do carrinho só atualiza se atualizar a página.
Pretendo que o estado seja atualizado, como efetuar essa confirmação sem mudar de página ou utilizar o F5?

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode utilizar o hook "woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments" que o Woocommerce dispara quando atualiza o carrinho. A função abaixo vai substituir o elemento HTML por um novo.

functions.php:

```
function meu_tema_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $w = ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count<1) ? 'width:25%' : 'width:20%';
    ob_start();
    ?>

    <div style="<?php echo $w ?>" class="footer-section <?php echo esc_html($woo);?>">
        <a href="<?php echo get_home_url();?>" title="Main"><i class="fa  fa-home"></i></a>
    </div>

    <?php
    $fragments['.footer-section'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'meu_tema_add_to_cart_fragment' );
```

Referência: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/

Comment: Leonel, thanks for your comment! Both post are working great. The problem is using a function outside functions.php.